# Returning `this` in a super method of inherited class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, this

let's say i have class `A` and class `B` which extends `A`,
here are the classes:

A:

```
public class A {
    public int x;
    public static int y;
    public A(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() { return x; }
    public static int getY() { return y; }
    public A get1() { return this; }
    public A get2() { return new B(x, y); }
}
```

B:

```
public class B extends A {
    public int x;
    public B(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        this.x = x*2;
        this.y = y*2;
    }
    public int getX() { return x; }
        public static int getY() { return y*3; }
    public A get1() {
        x++;
        return super.get1();
    }
    public A get2() { return get1(); }
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a1 = new A(5, 10);
    A a2 = a1.get2();
    A a3 = a2.get2();

    System.out.println("a1.x=" + a1.x);
    System.out.println("a1.y=" + a1.y);
    System.out.println("a2.x=" + a2.x);
    System.out.println("a2.getX()=" + a2.getX());
    System.out.println("a2.getY()=" + a2.getY());
    System.out.println("((B)a2).getY()=" + ((B)a2).getY());
    System.out.println("((B)a2).x=" + ((B)a2).x);
    System.out.println("a3 is A: " + (a3.getClass() == A.class));
    System.out.println("a3 is B: " + (a3 instanceof B));
    System.out.println("a3==a2: " + (a3 == a2));
}
```

My problem is with the `a2` and `a3` objects,
`a3` is basically `a2.get2()`, after following the method it will reach the `A` `get1()` method that returns `this`.

Since the method is found in class `A` i was sure it will only return the reference to `A` part of object `a2` and not a reference to the whole object,

So when i try this line:
    a3.getClass() == A.class
i will get `True`.

When i debugged `a3.getClass()` is "class B".

Can someone explain to me what the `return this` line actually does when it's inside a father class?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `a2` and `a3`? What you you mean by `a3` is basically `a2.get2()`. What do you mean by after following the method. Please provide all relevant information.

Comment: Well, so forget the "i was sure it will only return the reference to `A` part". There are no references to part of an object in Java.

Comment: And please don't post statements such as "i will get `True`" without corroberating code.

Comment: @ChetanKinger i updated the post with the relevant main function which for some reason i forgot in the initial post.

Comment: Wow, I am surprised at the fact that you left out the main method and assumed that people would just read your mind.

Comment: @ChetanKinger again i'm sorry but i didn't assume that, it was left out by mistake, notice i referenced the object names from the main program so i was going to paste it later, and forgot.

Comment: @argamanza My bad. It could have been an accident. See my answer for a step by step explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's trace the statements step by step :

1. `a1` is a reference to an instance of type `A`.
2. `a1.get2()` calls the `get2()` method in `A` which returns a reference to an instance of type `B` so `a2` refers to an instance of type `B`.
3. `a2.get2()` calls the `get2()` method in `B`. Remember that `a2` is an instance of type `B` so `this` refers to `B`.
4. `get2()` method in `B` calls the `get1()` method in `B`. `this` still refers to `B`.
5. `get1()` method in `B` calls `super.get1()`. This is where it can get a bit confusing. Even though you call the `get1` method from the parent class, `this` still refers to `B` at runtime.
6. Therefore, `super.get1()` returns `B`. `get1()` in `B` returns `B`. `get2()` in `B` returns `B`. Therefore, `a3` refers to an instance of type `B`.

From the java docs for `Object#getClass`

> public final Class getClass()
>
> Returns the runtime class of this Object

The `getClass` method returns the runtime class of an object so that's what you get when you call `getClass` on an a reference to an instance of type `B`. If `getClass` was not designed to return the actual instance type, it would have always returned `Object` which would make the method pointless.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `this` refers to the current object instance.  There is no "A part of the B object", i.e., there is no reference to a superclass from within a subclass.  Objects that are inherited are not divided into their different parts; you instantiate one object, and it is referred to by `this` from within instance methods, regardless of where those instance methods are declared.

So you have a B object, and `this` within a method declared in A.  If the method is called, directly or indirectly, from a B, then it is going to refer to that B object.